# How to set Cross-Origin headers to allow Data URLs?

Tags: javascript, svg, cors

I've got a javascript script that takes a SVG string and tries to put it on a canvas (to rasterize it). This works well in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari throws an error:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload(function() {
  context.drawImage(img, 0,0);
  exportImage.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
});
img.src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg>...</svg>";
```

When done this way, Safari throws an error at the `toDataURL()` call:

```
SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

if I add a `img.crossOrigin=''` to the `img` object before setting its `src`, I instead get a `Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.` error. I have the following in my `.htaccess` file for this site:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

But as this is a `data:` URL, this is not being queried? How do I properly set a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing header for scripts like this that are creating their own `data:` URLs?

Comment: I don't see what CORS headers would have to do with anything here, as there's no HTTP request involved.

Comment: I agree, but that's what Safari seems to be complaining about, which is what I'm trying to solve. So, is this a bug in Safari?

Comment: [It might be related to this Chromium issue.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=294129)

Comment: Seeing the exact same issue in IE11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [blobURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead of `dataURL`. [blobURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) has no cross-origin issue currently.

see [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and [objectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload(function() {
  context.drawImage(img, 0,0);
  exportImage.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
});
img.src=URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"><rect x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" fill="#00f"/></svg>'], {type : 'image/svg+xml'}));
```